# В чем проблема кода на python? Работа с PyQt5 [switch between windows]

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Никак не пойму, что сделала не так. Ошибки никакой не выдает, но при этом и работать нормально отказывается.

Собственно идея состояла в самом обычном открытии одного окна из другого, главного окна. Вроде как все должно работать, обработку нажатия на "*Edit*" (==actionAddRecord.text()) в функции `work_with_menu` выполнила, но при непосредственном нажатии на кнопку появляется пустое окно, все замирает и выключается... Вообще без понятия, где могла ошибиться.

*перекопировала все то, что есть в файле, ну так, на всякий случай*

```py
    from mainWindow import *
    from addRecordWindow import *
    from changeRecordWindow import *
    from deleteByKeyWindow import *
    from deleteByValueWindow import *
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton, QMessageBox
    import sys
    
    
    class AddRecordWin(QWidget, Ui_AddDialog):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.setupUi(self)
    
    
    class MyWin(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.setupUi(self)
    
            self.work_with_menu()
    
            self.show()
    
        def work_with_menu(self):
            self.actionAddRecord.triggered.connect(self.show_AddRecordWin)
    
        def show_AddRecordWin(self):
            self.add_w = AddRecordWin()
            self.add_w.show()
            self.add_w.exec_()
    
    '''    def closeEvent(self, event):
    
            reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
                "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes |
                QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
    
            if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
                event.accept()
            else:
                event.ignore()'''
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        app_w = AddRecordWin()
        my_app = MyWin()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**AddRecord**:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_AddDialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, AddDialog):
        AddDialog.setObjectName("AddDialog")
        AddDialog.resize(800, 450)
        AddDialog.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        AddDialog.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        AddDialog.setWindowOpacity(2.0)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(AddDialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 20, 201, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(AddDialog)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 70, 801, 16))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(AddDialog)
        self.splitter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 400, 186, 28))
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")
        self.okButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter)
        self.okButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.okButton.setDefault(True)
        self.okButton.setObjectName("okButton")
        self.cancelButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter)
        self.cancelButton.setObjectName("cancelButton")
        self.splitter_2 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(AddDialog)
        self.splitter_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(42, 200, 137, 45))
        self.splitter_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter_2.setObjectName("splitter_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.idEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_2)
        self.idEdit.setObjectName("idEdit")
        self.splitter_3 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(AddDialog)
        self.splitter_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(231, 200, 137, 45))
        self.splitter_3.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter_3.setObjectName("splitter_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.serialNameEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_3)
        self.serialNameEdit.setObjectName("serialNameEdit")
        self.splitter_4 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(AddDialog)
        self.splitter_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 200, 138, 45))
        self.splitter_4.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter_4.setObjectName("splitter_4")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_4)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.numSeriesEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_4)
        self.numSeriesEdit.setObjectName("numSeriesEdit")
        self.splitter_5 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(AddDialog)
        self.splitter_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 200, 137, 45))
        self.splitter_5.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter_5.setObjectName("splitter_5")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_5)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.isWatchedEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_5)
        self.isWatchedEdit.setObjectName("isWatchedEdit")
        self.label_2.setBuddy(self.idEdit)
        self.label_3.setBuddy(self.serialNameEdit)
        self.label_4.setBuddy(self.numSeriesEdit)
        self.label_5.setBuddy(self.isWatchedEdit)

        self.retranslateUi(AddDialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(AddDialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, AddDialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        AddDialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("AddDialog", "Adding new record"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "Adding new record"))
        self.okButton.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "Ok"))
        self.cancelButton.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "Cancel"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "id:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "serial_name:"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "number_of_series:"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "is_watched:"))
```

**MainWindow**:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 450)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 450))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 450))
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 502, 271))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 370, 171, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 10, 551, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 120, 111, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 160, 21, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 160, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 200, 71, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 200, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 240, 111, 16))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 240, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 280, 71, 16))
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 280, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-3, 40, 761, 16))
        self.line.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.showButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.showButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 330, 71, 31))
        self.showButton.setObjectName("showButton")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 60, 321, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setNativeMenuBar(True)
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuEdit = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuEdit.setObjectName("menuEdit")
        self.menuDelete_record = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuEdit)
        self.menuDelete_record.setObjectName("menuDelete_record")
        self.menuCreate = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuCreate.setObjectName("menuCreate")
        self.menuImport = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuImport.setObjectName("menuImport")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionNew = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNew.setObjectName("actionNew")
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionSave = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave.setObjectName("actionSave")
        self.actionClean = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionClean.setObjectName("actionClean")
        self.actionDelete = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDelete.setObjectName("actionDelete")
        self.actionAddRecord = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAddRecord.setObjectName("actionAddRecord")
        self.actionChangeRecord = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionChangeRecord.setObjectName("actionChangeRecord")
        self.actionDelete_by_key = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDelete_by_key.setObjectName("actionDelete_by_key")
        self.actionDelete_by_value = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDelete_by_value.setObjectName("actionDelete_by_value")
        self.actionBackup = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionBackup.setObjectName("actionBackup")
        self.actionXlsx = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionXlsx.setObjectName("actionXlsx")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionNew)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuFile.addSeparator()
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave)
        self.menuFile.addSeparator()
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionClean)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionDelete)
        self.menuDelete_record.addAction(self.actionDelete_by_key)
        self.menuDelete_record.addAction(self.actionDelete_by_value)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionAddRecord)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionChangeRecord)
        self.menuEdit.addSeparator()
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.menuDelete_record.menuAction())
        self.menuCreate.addAction(self.actionBackup)
        self.menuImport.addAction(self.actionXlsx)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuEdit.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuCreate.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuImport.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit, self.lineEdit_2)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit_2, self.lineEdit_3)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit_3, self.lineEdit_4)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit_4, self.tableWidget)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "id"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "serial_name"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "number_of_series"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "is_watched"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Creator: Prishchepa Kseniya"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Good afternoon! It is the fisrt homeproject: \"File Data Base\"!"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Searching by..."))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "id"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "serial_name"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "number_of_series"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "is_watched"))
        self.showButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Show"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "You can choose only one field of searching!"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuEdit.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.menuDelete_record.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete record..."))
        self.menuCreate.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Create..."))
        self.menuImport.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Import..."))
        self.actionNew.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open ..."))
        self.actionSave.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save ..."))
        self.actionClean.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clean"))
        self.actionDelete.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete"))
        self.actionAddRecord.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add record"))
        self.actionChangeRecord.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Change record"))
        self.actionDelete_by_key.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "by key"))
        self.actionDelete_by_value.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "by value"))
        self.actionBackup.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "back-up file [.txt]"))
        self.actionXlsx.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "to [.xlsx] format"))
```

[image: запуск программы]

По какой-то причине, во время того, как мою программу выбрасывает, нельзя сделать скрин экрана, пришлось фотографировать...

[image: пытаюсь открыть диалоговое окно]

P.s. Так как являюсь абсолютным новичком, разного рода советы по оформлению кода только приветствуются)

Comment: Опубликуйте модули `mainWindow.py`, `addRecordWindow.py` и другие если они задействованы в вашем примере.

Comment: я вас просил модули, а не картинки. Те модули, которые вы импортируете в начале примера `from mainWindow import *`. и т.д.

Comment: Все, не сразу заметила комментарий, сейчас добавила

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я отметил строки, которые надо поменять.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton, QMessageBox
#from mainWindow import *
#from addRecordWindow import *
#from changeRecordWindow import *
#from deleteByKeyWindow import *
#from deleteByValueWindow import *


class Ui_AddDialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, AddDialog):
        AddDialog.setObjectName("AddDialog")
        AddDialog.resize(500, 300)
        AddDialog.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 300))
        AddDialog.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 300))
        AddDialog.setWindowOpacity(2.0)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(AddDialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 241, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(AddDialog)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 40, 501, 16))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(AddDialog)
        self.splitter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 260, 186, 28))
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")
        self.okButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter)
        self.okButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.okButton.setDefault(True)
        self.okButton.setObjectName("okButton")
        self.cancelButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter)
        self.cancelButton.setObjectName("cancelButton")
        self.splitter_2 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(AddDialog)
        self.splitter_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 137, 45))
        self.splitter_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter_2.setObjectName("splitter_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_2)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.splitter_3 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(AddDialog)
        self.splitter_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 137, 45))
        self.splitter_3.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter_3.setObjectName("splitter_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_3)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.splitter_4 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(AddDialog)
        self.splitter_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(175, 150, 138, 45))
        self.splitter_4.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter_4.setObjectName("splitter_4")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_4)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_4)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.splitter_5 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(AddDialog)
        self.splitter_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(332, 150, 137, 45))
        self.splitter_5.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter_5.setObjectName("splitter_5")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_5)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_5)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.label_2.setBuddy(self.lineEdit)
        self.label_3.setBuddy(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.label_4.setBuddy(self.lineEdit_3)
        self.label_5.setBuddy(self.lineEdit_4)

        self.retranslateUi(AddDialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(AddDialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, AddDialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        AddDialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("AddDialog", "Adding new record"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "Adding new record"))
        self.okButton.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "Ок"))
        self.cancelButton.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "Cancel"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "id:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "serial_name:"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "number_of_series:"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "is_watched:"))


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 450)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 450))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 450))
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 502, 271))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 370, 171, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 10, 551, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 120, 111, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 160, 21, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 160, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 200, 71, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 200, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 240, 111, 16))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 240, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 280, 71, 16))
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 280, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-3, 40, 761, 16))
        self.line.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 330, 71, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 60, 321, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setNativeMenuBar(True)
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuEdit = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuEdit.setObjectName("menuEdit")
        self.menuDelete_record = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuEdit)
        self.menuDelete_record.setObjectName("menuDelete_record")
        self.menuCreate = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuCreate.setObjectName("menuCreate")
        self.menuImport = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuImport.setObjectName("menuImport")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionNew = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNew.setObjectName("actionNew")
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionSave = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave.setObjectName("actionSave")
        self.actionClean = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionClean.setObjectName("actionClean")
        self.actionDelete = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDelete.setObjectName("actionDelete")
        self.actionAddRecord = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAddRecord.setObjectName("actionAddRecord")
        self.actionChangeRecord = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionChangeRecord.setObjectName("actionChangeRecord")
        self.actionDelete_by_key = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDelete_by_key.setObjectName("actionDelete_by_key")
        self.actionDelete_by_value = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDelete_by_value.setObjectName("actionDelete_by_value")
        self.actionBackup = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionBackup.setObjectName("actionBackup")
        self.actionXlsx = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionXlsx.setObjectName("actionXlsx")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionNew)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuFile.addSeparator()
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave)
        self.menuFile.addSeparator()
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionClean)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionDelete)
        self.menuDelete_record.addAction(self.actionDelete_by_key)
        self.menuDelete_record.addAction(self.actionDelete_by_value)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionAddRecord)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionChangeRecord)
        self.menuEdit.addSeparator()
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.menuDelete_record.menuAction())
        self.menuCreate.addAction(self.actionBackup)
        self.menuImport.addAction(self.actionXlsx)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuEdit.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuCreate.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuImport.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit, self.lineEdit_2)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit_2, self.lineEdit_3)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit_3, self.lineEdit_4)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit_4, self.tableWidget)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "id"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "serial_name"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "number_of_series"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "is_watched"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Creator: Prishchepa Kseniya"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Good afternoon! It is the fisrt homeproject: \"File Data Base\"!"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Searching by..."))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "id"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "serial_name"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "number_of_series"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "is_watched"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Show"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "You can choose only one field of searching!"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuEdit.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.menuDelete_record.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete record..."))
        self.menuCreate.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Create..."))
        self.menuImport.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Import..."))
        self.actionNew.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open ..."))
        self.actionSave.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save ..."))
        self.actionClean.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clean"))
        self.actionDelete.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete"))
        self.actionAddRecord.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add record"))
        self.actionChangeRecord.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Change record"))
        self.actionDelete_by_key.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "by key"))
        self.actionDelete_by_value.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "by value"))
        self.actionBackup.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "back-up file [.txt]"))
        self.actionXlsx.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "to [.xlsx] format"))


class AddRecordWin(QWidget, Ui_AddDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


class MyWin(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.work_with_menu()

#        self.show()

    def work_with_menu(self):
        self.actionAddRecord.triggered.connect(self.show_AddRecordWin)

    def show_AddRecordWin(self):
        self.add_w = AddRecordWin()
        self.add_w.setupUi(self)                                        # +

        self.add_w.show()
#        self.add_w.exec_()

'''    def closeEvent(self, event):

        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
            "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes |
            QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()'''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#    app_w = AddRecordWin()
    my_app = MyWin()
    my_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Все заработало!!!