# Как организовать передачу данных в pyqt5? (Попытка написания наивной файловой БД)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, интерфейс

Раннее уже писала вопрос, в котором описывала часть моей текущей работы.

Вот ссылка:
[В чем проблема кода на python? Работа с PyQt5 [switch between windows]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040168/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-pyqt5-switch-between-windows)

Там представлен код для "mainWindow.py", "addRecordWindow.py"

**А вот и сам вопрос**: Как мне следует организовать передачу данных? Идея заключается в том, чтобы из меню на главном окне я могла открыть новое (для добавления новой записи в файловую БД).

При этом, после ввода информации о новой записи, мне нужно чтобы на главном окне НЕ было отображения этих изменений, они должны записаться в переменную `hash_table`, отображение должно будет происходить только после нажатия на кнопку `show`, но над этим мне еще предстоит работать... Кстати, я, видимо, опять где-то накосячила и после нажатия на кнопку `Ok` у меня выбрасывает всю программу...

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal

from mainWindow import *
from addRecordWindow import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QMessageBox, QFileDialog
import sys
from HashTable import *


class AddRecordWin(QWidget, Ui_AddDialog):
    adding_data = pyqtSignal(str, str, str, str) # Создала атрибут для хранения информации

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.send_data)

    def send_data(self):
        self.adding_data.emit(self.idEdit.text(), self.serialNameEdit.text(), self.numSeriesEdit.text(),
                              self.isWatchedEdit.text()) # Пытаюсь записать данные из формы при нажатии на кнопку "Ok"
        self.close()


class MyWin(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.initialize_windows() # создаю окна
        self.work_with_menu() # описываю доступ к ним через меню

        # после открытия окна для добавления новой записи забираю данные
        self.add_w.adding_data[str, str, str, str].connect(self.handle_input)

    def handle_input(self, key, val1, val2, val3):
        self.hash_table.__add__(key, val1, val2, val3)

    def initialize_windows(self):
        self.add_w = AddRecordWin()

    def work_with_menu(self):
        self.actionNew.triggered.connect(self.create_new_hash_table)
        self.actionOpen.triggered.connect(self.open_hash_table)
        self.actionSave.triggered.connect(self.save_hash_table)
        self.actionAddRecord.triggered.connect(self.show_AddRecordWin)

    def create_new_hash_table(self):
        self.hash_table = HashTable()

    def open_hash_table(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/data.txt', "Image files (*.jpg *.gif)")
        file = open(filename)
        name_hash_table = file.read()
        #self.tableWidget. # Хочется, чтобы здесь отобразилась полученная информация
        self.textEdit.setText(name_hash_table)

    def save_hash_table(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Open file', '/data.txt', "Image files (*.jpg *.gif)")
        file = open(filename)
        name_hash_table = file.read()
        self.hash_table.__save_data_base__(name_hash_table)

    def show_AddRecordWin(self):
        self.add_w.setupUi(self)
        self.add_w.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):

        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
            "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes |
            QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    my_app = MyWin()
    my_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В моем классе `HashTable` еще много чего нужно править, но функция `__add__` должна исправно добавлять новую запись.

[EDIT] Код моей наивной hash table (исправленный + новая функция для открытия файла `open_data_base`):

```py
import os


class Entry:
    def __init__(self, key, value1, value2=None, value3=None):
        self.hash = None
        self.key = key
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
        self.value3 = value3
        self.is_deleted = False

    '''def __eq__(self, other):
        if (self.hash == other.hash and self.key == other.key and self.value1 == other.value1 and
                self.value2 == other.value2 and self.value3 == other.value3 and self.is_deleted == other.is_deleted):
            return True
        else:
            return False'''


class HashTable(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.table = [None] * 10
        self.load_factor = .75
        self.current_size = 0
        file_hashes = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'w')
        file_hashes.close()
        file_output_result_search = open('service_files/output_result_search.txt', 'w')
        file_output_result_search.close()

    def str(self):
        out_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'r')
        hashes = out_file.read().splitlines()
        out_file.close()
        for hash_ in hashes:
            print(self.str_element(int(hash_)))
        return None

    def str_element(self, hash_):
        if self.table[hash_].value2 is None and self.table[hash_].value3 is None:
            item = ['{!r}: {!r}'.format(self.table[hash_].key, self.table[hash_].value1)]
        elif self.table[hash_].value2 is None:
            item = ['{!r}: [{!r}, {!r}]'.format(self.table[hash_].key, self.table[hash_].value1,
                                                self.table[hash_].value3)]
        elif self.table[hash_].value3 is None:
            item = ['{!r}: [{!r}, {!r}]'.format(self.table[hash_].key, self.table[hash_].value1,
                                                self.table[hash_].value2)]
        else:
            item = ['{!r}: [{!r}, {!r}, {!r}]'.format(self.table[hash_].key, self.table[hash_].value1,
                                                      self.table[hash_].value2, self.table[hash_].value3)]
        return '{' + ', '.join(item) + '}'

    '''def __setitem__(self, key, value1, value2=None, value3=None):
        self.__clear__()
        entry = Entry(key, value1, value2, value3)
        for i in range(len(self.table)):
            entry.hash = self.__get_hash_code(key)
            if self.table[entry.hash] is None or self.table[entry.hash].is_deleted:
                self.table[entry.hash] = entry
                in_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'w')
                print(entry.hash, sep='\n', file=in_file)
                in_file.close()
                self.current_size += 1
                if float(self.current_size) / len(self.table) >= self.load_factor:
                    self.__resize_table()'''

    def add(self, key, value1, value2=None, value3=None):
        entry = Entry(key, value1, value2, value3)
        entry.hash = self.__get_hash_code(key)
        if self.table[entry.hash] is None or self.table[entry.hash].is_deleted:
            self.table[entry.hash] = entry
            in_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'a')
            print(entry.hash, sep='\n', file=in_file)
            in_file.close()
            self.current_size += 1
            if float(self.current_size) / len(self.table) >= self.load_factor:
                self.__resize_table()

    def getitem(self, key):
        index = self.__get_hash_code(key)
        if self.table[index] is not None:
            if self.table[index].key == key:
                if self.table[index].is_deleted:
                    raise KeyError('Key is not in the map')
                else:
                    return self.table[index].value1, self.table[index].value2, self.table[index].value3

        elif self.table[index] is None:
            raise KeyError('Key is not in the data base')
        else:
            raise KeyError('Hmm something has gone wrong here')

    def getitem_value(self, value1=None, value2=None, value3=None):
        self._binary_search(value1, value2, value3)
        in_file = open('service_files/output_result_search.txt', 'r')
        keys = in_file.read().splitlines()
        in_file.close()
        for key in keys:
            self.getitem(key)

    def _binary_search(self, value1=None, value2=None, value3=None):
        in_file = open('service_files/output_result_search.txt', 'w')
        out_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'r')
        hashes = out_file.read().splitlines()
        out_file.close()
        if (value1 is not None) and (value2 is None) and (value3 is None):
            for hash_ in hashes:
                if self.table[int(hash_)].value1 == value1:
                    print(self.table[int(hash_)].key, sep='\n', file=in_file)
        elif (value1 is None) and (value2 is not None) and (value3 is None):
            for hash_ in hashes:
                if self.table[int(hash_)].value2 == value2:
                    print(self.table[int(hash_)].key, sep='\n', file=in_file)
        elif (value1 is None) and (value2 is None) and (value3 is not None):
            for hash_ in hashes:
                if self.table[int(hash_)].value3 == value3:
                    print(self.table[int(hash_)].key, sep='\n', file=in_file)
        else:
            return 'Error! Please, chose ONE field of search!'
        in_file.close()

    def __get_hash_code(self, key):
        return hash(key) % len(self.table)

    def __resize_table(self):
        new_table = [None] * (len(self.table) * 2)
        for i in range(len(self.table)):
            new_table[i] = self.table[i]

        self.table = new_table

    def __change__(self, key, value1, value2=None, value3=None):
        entry = Entry(key, value1, value2, value3)
        entry.hash = self.__get_hash_code(key)
        if self.table[entry.hash] is not None:
            self.table[entry.hash] = entry

    def delitem(self, key):
        index = self.__get_hash_code(key)
        if self.table[index] is not None:
            if self.table[index].key == key:
                if self.table[index].is_deleted:
                    raise KeyError('Key is not in the map')
                else:
                    self.table[index].is_deleted = True

                    out_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'r')
                    hashes = out_file.read().splitlines()
                    out_file.close()

                    hashes.remove(str(self.table[index].hash))

                    in_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'w')
                    print(hashes, sep='\n', file=in_file)
                    in_file.close()

                    self.current_size -= 1

    def delitem_value(self, value1=None, value2=None, value3=None):
        self._binary_search(value1, value2, value3)
        in_file = open('service_files/output_result_search.txt', 'r')
        keys = in_file.read().splitlines()
        in_file.close()
        for key in keys:
            self.delitem(key)

    def open_data_base(self, name_file):
        if self.table:
            self.clean()
        with open(name_file) as out_file:
            data = out_file.read().splitlines()
        out_file.close()
        for item in data:
            item = item.split(';')
            self.add(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3])
        return None

    def save_data_base(self, name_file):
        in_file = open(name_file, 'w')
        out_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'r')
        hashes = out_file.read().splitlines()
        out_file.close()
        for hash_ in hashes:
            print(self.table[int(hash_)].key, self.table[int(hash_)].value1, self.table[int(hash_)].value2,
                  self.table[int(hash_)].value3, sep=';', file=in_file)
        in_file.close()
        return None

    def clean(self):
        file_hashes = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'w')
        file_hashes.close()
        file_output_result_search = open('service_files/output_result_search.txt', 'w')
        file_output_result_search.close()
        self.table = [None] * 10
        self.current_size = 0

    def __del__(self):
        os.remove('service_files/hashes.txt')
        os.remove('service_files/output_result_search.txt')
        del self.table
        del self.load_factor
        del self.current_size
```

На этом мои проблемы не закончились на самом деле... У меня выбрасывает окна для сохранения/открытия файла и ничего не открывается...

Скорее всего все это связано с моими скудными познаниями в том, как подключить какие-то функции к кнопкам, как обмениваться информацией... Я читала разные примеры в интернете, но мне сложно адаптировать полученную информацию под мой случай, потому прошу помощи.

P.s. Формулировка получилась довольно сумбурной, потому задавайте, пожалуйста вопросы, если нужно что-то дописать/дополнить в описании, то я с радостью это сделаю!

Comment: 1) `self.hash_table` vs `self.hesh_table = `. Опечатка? 2) Зачем вам магический метод `__add__` (это для работы оператора `+`)? Используйте свой метод `add`. 3) нет атрибутов в `def handle_input(self):`, которые сигнал положил бы в метод 4) `self.hash_table.__add__(str, str, str, str)` тоже странное, уверен, вы хотели туда положить параметры из 3)

Comment: Магический метод? Имеете в виду, что лучше назвать методы класса `HashTable` не `__add__`, а `add`? (Работа оператора '+' в планы не входила)

Comment: Да, все методы, что начинаются и закончиваются на `__` являются магическими и используются питоном для всях штучек. Например, вместо `self.hash_table.__add__(str, str, str, str)` должно сработать `self.hash_table + (str, str, str, str)`. Это и касается `__str__` -- 'тот метод вызывается для `str()` еще при передаче в `print` и т.п. Если хотите сделать методы приватными, то добавляйте нижнее подчеркивание только слева

Comment: А, все, поняла) Сейчас попытаюсь вникнуть в Ваши слова в первом комментарии

Comment: Вы только что сделали какую-то правку в вашем вопросе. Если вы редактировали вопрос с целью уточнения каких либо вопросов, то этого лучше не делать. Нужно задать новый вопрос, так как трудно отследить что в вопросе появилось нового. Этот вопрос уже отработан. И не забывайте публиковать последнее состояние ваших модулей.

Comment: Поняла, сейчас верну как было, ну, постараюсь... Старую версию HashTable не сохранила

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)**
У вас точно есть проблема с методом `handle_input`, у него нет параметров, что он мог бы передать от сигнала:

```
    ...

        # после открытия окна для добавления новой записи забираю данные
        self.add_w.adding_data[str, str, str, str].connect(self.handle_input)

    def handle_input(self, id_value, serial_name, num_series, is_watched):
        # Отправляю данные в созданный
        self.hash_table.__add__(id_value, serial_name, num_series, is_watched)
```

---

**2)**
Рекомендую переименовать метод `def __add__(self, key, value1, value2=None, value3=None):` в `def add(self, key, value1, value2=None, value3=None):`.

Два нижних подчеркивания слева и справа объявляют метод магическим, что может привнести всякие сюрпризы.
Т.е. лучше вообще отказаться от практики называния своих методов (тот же `__save_data_base__`) таким образом, если только намеренно не хотите перекрыть магический метод.

---

**3)**
Тут опечатка? Переменная `self.hesh_table` нигде больше не используется

```
def create_new_hash_table(self):
    self.hesh_table = HashTable()
```

Т.к. сейчас обращение к `self.hash_table` (например в `handle_input` и `save_hash_table`) вызовут исключение

---

**4)**
Если методы `handle_input` или `save_hash_table` будут вызваны раньше `create_new_hash_table`, то будет исключение. Возможно этого никогда не будет, но я бы добавил в конструктор (`__init__`) инициализацию поля: `self.hash_table = None`, а в методах `handle_input` и `save_hash_table` проверку, что `self.hash_table` существует перед вызовом его методов, пример:

```
def handle_input(self, key, val1, val2, val3):
    if self.hash_table:
        self.hash_table.add(key, val1, val2, val3)
```

Подобное нужно и для `save_hash_table`

---

**5)**
В `filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Open file', '/data.txt', "Image files (*.jpg *.gif)")` ошибка из-за того, что он возвращает кортеж из двух элементов: путь и фильтр.

Правильно так:

```
filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Open file', '/data.txt', "Image files (*.jpg *.gif)")[0]
```

Можно и так:

```
filename, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Open file', '/data.txt', "Image files (*.jpg *.gif)")
```

---

**6)**

В `save_hash_table` у вас будет ошибка в `open` если указанного файла не существует:

```
    def save_hash_table(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Open file', '/data.txt', "Image files (*.jpg *.gif)")
        file = open(filename)
```

Потому что, [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) имеет такую сигнатуру:

```
open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)
```

Т.е. по умолчанию файл считывается, а не записывается. Чтобы файл записывался нужно вторым параметром режим записи указывать:

```
file = open(filename, 'w')
```

И для записи в файл используется метод `write`: `file.write(...)`

Советую, для открытия файлов использовать конструкцию `with`, например:

```
def save_hash_table(self):
    filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Open file', '/data.txt', "Image files (*.jpg *.gif)")
    with open(filename) as file:
        name_hash_table = file.read()
    self.hash_table.__save_data_base__(name_hash_table)
```

Comment: Да, опечатка, сейчас поправлю

Comment: Так, все магические методы превратила в обычные, параметры в handle_input добавила

Comment: Но по какой-то причине, после нажатия 'Ok' в окне для введения новой записи программу все равно выкидывает...

Comment: В других классах тоже поменяли? Например `self.hash_table.__add__`. У вас есть код отлова не пойманных исключений https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/3587753f6b427adbcc6e5951ff912aad94c4835f/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/hook_exceptions_in_Qt.py#L11? Добавьте его и тогда если что трасса стека будет при падении, что облегчит поиск проблемы

Comment: Да, поменяла. Как раз таки в `handle_input`, где потом эта функция у `hash_table` вызывается

Comment: Error:  AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'text':
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/data_bases_lab1/main.py", line 102, in save_hash_table
    file = open(filename.text())
(выводит при сохранении файла) Изначально там не было .text(), решила посмотреть, что будет, если добавлю, но выдал точно такую же ошибку, как и при 'filename'

Comment: `filename` у вас это кортеж (tuple) и у него действительно нет атрибута text. Обновил ответ, см `5)`

Comment: Error:  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/data.txt':
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/data_bases/main.py", line 102, in save_hash_table
    file = open(filename) Вот что он мне вывел в этот раз... Он не согласен с местом сохранения?

Comment: @treiina, очень новичковые у вас вопросы... (не парьтесь, все были зелеными) платили бы мне за это все :) Обновил ответ, см `6)` :)

Comment: Потому что и являюсь новичком... Но вот мой последний вопрос это да, это уже просто нервный срыв, обычно такую фигню не творю (не описала, с какой целью файл открывается) Спасибо Вам большое, что сидите тут со мной, но просто не знаю уже, любая ошибка в ступор вгоняет...

Comment: @treiina, все нормально, понимаю :)

Comment: @treiina, ок, обращайтесь :)

Comment: @treiina, информация предоставленная gil9red, является не только правильной,
но и очень полезной. Не забудьте отметить ответ как `Полезный`, 
у вас уже для этого достаточно репутации.