# В чем ошибка? Не могу вытащить данные из формы PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

Продолжаю свою серию вопросов о том, как написать интерфейс в PyQt5.
Прошлые вопросы: [Вопрос 1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040168/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-pyqt5-switch-between-windows), [Вопрос 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040384/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-pyqt5-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%91%D0%94).

Итак, почему не получается "достать" информацию из формы? 
Последовательность действий (как я ее вижу):

- открыть главное окно при запуске программы,
- создать новую БД (**`File->New`**),
- добавить новую запись (**`Edit->Add record`**),
- ввести данные,
- нажать ок.

Т.к. я до сих пор не обработала вывод информации на главный экран, проверяю значения полученных из формы переменных с помощью функции `print()` в нужных мне частях кода (см. ниже пометила комментарием местонахождение этих print-ов)

Что у меня выводит: `{'': ['', '', '']}` 
(Но значения в форме я не оставляла пустыми...)

Код для запуска:

```py
import sys
from HashTable import *

from mainWindow import *
from addRecordWindow import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QMessageBox, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)

    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print('Error: ', text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()


class AddRecordWin(QWidget, Ui_AddDialog):

    adding_data = pyqtSignal(str, str, str, str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.send_data)

    def send_data(self):
        self.adding_data.emit(self.idEdit.text(), self.serialNameEdit.text(), self.numSeriesEdit.text(),
                              self.isWatchedEdit.text())
        print(self.idEdit.text(), self.serialNameEdit.text(), self.numSeriesEdit.text(), self.isWatchedEdit.text()) # Пытаюсь посмотреть что лежит в собранных данных, временная мера
        self.close()


class MyWin(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.hash_table = None

        self.initialize_windows()
        self.work_with_menu()

    def handle_input(self, key, val1, val2, val3):
        if self.hash_table:
            self.hash_table.add(key, val1, val2, val3)
            self.hash_table.str() # Пытаюсь взглянуть на полученное, но все время выдает: {'': ['', '', '']}

    def initialize_windows(self):
        self.add_w = AddRecordWin()

    def work_with_menu(self):
        self.actionNew.triggered.connect(self.create_new_hash_table)
        self.actionOpen.triggered.connect(self.open_hash_table)
        self.actionSave.triggered.connect(self.save_hash_table)
        self.actionClean.triggered.connect(self.clean_hash_table)
        self.actionAddRecord.triggered.connect(self.show_AddRecordWin)

    def create_new_hash_table(self):
        self.hash_table = HashTable()

    def open_hash_table(self):
        self.create_new_hash_table()
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/data', "Image files (*.txt)")[0]
        self.hash_table.open_data_base(filename)
        self.hash_table.str()

    def save_hash_table(self):
        if self.hash_table.current_size:
            #self.hash_table.str()
            filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Open file', '/data', "Image files (*.txt)")[0]
            self.hash_table.save_data_base(filename)

    def clean_hash_table(self):
        self.hash_table.clean()

    def show_AddRecordWin(self):
        self.add_w.setupUi(self)
        self.add_w.show()
        self.add_w.adding_data[str, str, str, str].connect(self.handle_input)


sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    my_app = MyWin()
    my_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Модуль **`mainWindow.py`**:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 450)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 450))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 450))
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 502, 271))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 370, 171, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 10, 551, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 120, 111, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 160, 21, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 160, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 200, 71, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 200, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 240, 111, 16))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 240, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 280, 71, 16))
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 280, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-3, 40, 761, 16))
        self.line.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.showButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.showButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 330, 71, 31))
        self.showButton.setObjectName("showButton")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 60, 321, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setNativeMenuBar(True)
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuEdit = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuEdit.setObjectName("menuEdit")
        self.menuDelete_record = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuEdit)
        self.menuDelete_record.setObjectName("menuDelete_record")
        self.menuCreate = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuCreate.setObjectName("menuCreate")
        self.menuImport = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuImport.setObjectName("menuImport")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionNew = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNew.setObjectName("actionNew")
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionSave = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave.setObjectName("actionSave")
        self.actionClean = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionClean.setObjectName("actionClean")
        self.actionDelete = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDelete.setObjectName("actionDelete")
        self.actionAddRecord = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAddRecord.setObjectName("actionAddRecord")
        self.actionChangeRecord = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionChangeRecord.setObjectName("actionChangeRecord")
        self.actionDelete_by_key = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDelete_by_key.setObjectName("actionDelete_by_key")
        self.actionDelete_by_value = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDelete_by_value.setObjectName("actionDelete_by_value")
        self.actionBackup = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionBackup.setObjectName("actionBackup")
        self.actionXlsx = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionXlsx.setObjectName("actionXlsx")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionNew)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuFile.addSeparator()
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave)
        self.menuFile.addSeparator()
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionClean)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionDelete)
        self.menuDelete_record.addAction(self.actionDelete_by_key)
        self.menuDelete_record.addAction(self.actionDelete_by_value)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionAddRecord)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionChangeRecord)
        self.menuEdit.addSeparator()
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.menuDelete_record.menuAction())
        self.menuCreate.addAction(self.actionBackup)
        self.menuImport.addAction(self.actionXlsx)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuEdit.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuCreate.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuImport.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit, self.lineEdit_2)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit_2, self.lineEdit_3)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit_3, self.lineEdit_4)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit_4, self.tableWidget)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "id"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "serial_name"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "number_of_series"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "is_watched"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Creator: Prishchepa Kseniya"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Good afternoon! It is the fisrt homeproject: \"File Data Base\"!"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Searching by..."))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "id"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "serial_name"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "number_of_series"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "is_watched"))
        self.showButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Show"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "You can choose only one field of searching!"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuEdit.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.menuDelete_record.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete record..."))
        self.menuCreate.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Create..."))
        self.menuImport.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Import..."))
        self.actionNew.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open ..."))
        self.actionSave.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save ..."))
        self.actionClean.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clean"))
        self.actionDelete.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete"))
        self.actionAddRecord.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add record"))
        self.actionChangeRecord.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Change record"))
        self.actionDelete_by_key.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "by key"))
        self.actionDelete_by_value.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "by value"))
        self.actionBackup.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "back-up file [.txt]"))
        self.actionXlsx.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "to [.xlsx] format"))
```

Модуль **`addRecordWindow.py`**:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_AddDialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, AddDialog):
        AddDialog.setObjectName("AddDialog")
        AddDialog.resize(800, 450)
        AddDialog.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        AddDialog.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        AddDialog.setWindowOpacity(2.0)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(AddDialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 20, 201, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(AddDialog)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 70, 801, 16))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(AddDialog)
        self.splitter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 400, 186, 28))
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")
        self.okButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter)
        self.okButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.okButton.setDefault(True)
        self.okButton.setObjectName("okButton")
        self.cancelButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter)
        self.cancelButton.setObjectName("cancelButton")
        self.splitter_2 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(AddDialog)
        self.splitter_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(42, 200, 137, 45))
        self.splitter_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter_2.setObjectName("splitter_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.idEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_2)
        self.idEdit.setObjectName("idEdit")
        self.splitter_3 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(AddDialog)
        self.splitter_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(231, 200, 137, 45))
        self.splitter_3.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter_3.setObjectName("splitter_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.serialNameEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_3)
        self.serialNameEdit.setObjectName("serialNameEdit")
        self.splitter_4 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(AddDialog)
        self.splitter_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 200, 138, 45))
        self.splitter_4.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter_4.setObjectName("splitter_4")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_4)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.numSeriesEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_4)
        self.numSeriesEdit.setObjectName("numSeriesEdit")
        self.splitter_5 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(AddDialog)
        self.splitter_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 200, 137, 45))
        self.splitter_5.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter_5.setObjectName("splitter_5")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_5)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.isWatchedEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_5)
        self.isWatchedEdit.setObjectName("isWatchedEdit")
        self.label_2.setBuddy(self.idEdit)
        self.label_3.setBuddy(self.serialNameEdit)
        self.label_4.setBuddy(self.numSeriesEdit)
        self.label_5.setBuddy(self.isWatchedEdit)

        self.retranslateUi(AddDialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(AddDialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, AddDialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        AddDialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("AddDialog", "Adding new record"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "Adding new record"))
        self.okButton.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "Ok"))
        self.cancelButton.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "Cancel"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "id:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "serial_name:"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "number_of_series:"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("AddDialog", "is_watched:"))
```

---

[EDIT] **`Добавила класс HashTable()`**:

```py
import os


class Entry:
    def __init__(self, key, value1, value2=None, value3=None):
        self.hash = None
        self.key = key
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
        self.value3 = value3
        self.is_deleted = False

    '''def __eq__(self, other):
        if (self.hash == other.hash and self.key == other.key and self.value1 == other.value1 and
                self.value2 == other.value2 and self.value3 == other.value3 and self.is_deleted == other.is_deleted):
            return True
        else:
            return False'''


class HashTable(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.table = [None] * 10
        self.load_factor = .75
        self.current_size = 0
        file_hashes = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'w')
        file_hashes.close()
        file_output_result_search = open('service_files/output_result_search.txt', 'w')
        file_output_result_search.close()

    def str(self):
        out_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'r')
        hashes = out_file.read().splitlines()
        out_file.close()
        for hash_ in hashes:
            print(self.str_element(int(hash_)))
        return None

    def str_element(self, hash_):
        if self.table[hash_].value2 is None and self.table[hash_].value3 is None:
            item = ['{!r}: {!r}'.format(self.table[hash_].key, self.table[hash_].value1)]
        elif self.table[hash_].value2 is None:
            item = ['{!r}: [{!r}, {!r}]'.format(self.table[hash_].key, self.table[hash_].value1,
                                                self.table[hash_].value3)]
        elif self.table[hash_].value3 is None:
            item = ['{!r}: [{!r}, {!r}]'.format(self.table[hash_].key, self.table[hash_].value1,
                                                self.table[hash_].value2)]
        else:
            item = ['{!r}: [{!r}, {!r}, {!r}]'.format(self.table[hash_].key, self.table[hash_].value1,
                                                      self.table[hash_].value2, self.table[hash_].value3)]
        return '{' + ', '.join(item) + '}'

    '''def __setitem__(self, key, value1, value2=None, value3=None):
        self.__clear__()
        entry = Entry(key, value1, value2, value3)
        for i in range(len(self.table)):
            entry.hash = self.__get_hash_code(key)
            if self.table[entry.hash] is None or self.table[entry.hash].is_deleted:
                self.table[entry.hash] = entry
                in_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'w')
                print(entry.hash, sep='\n', file=in_file)
                in_file.close()
                self.current_size += 1
                if float(self.current_size) / len(self.table) >= self.load_factor:
                    self.__resize_table()'''

    def add(self, key, value1, value2=None, value3=None):
        entry = Entry(key, value1, value2, value3)
        entry.hash = self.__get_hash_code(key)
        if self.table[entry.hash] is None or self.table[entry.hash].is_deleted:
            self.table[entry.hash] = entry
            in_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'a')
            print(entry.hash, sep='\n', file=in_file)
            in_file.close()
            self.current_size += 1
            if float(self.current_size) / len(self.table) >= self.load_factor:
                self.__resize_table()

    def getitem(self, key):
        index = self.__get_hash_code(key)
        if self.table[index] is not None:
            if self.table[index].key == key:
                if self.table[index].is_deleted:
                    raise KeyError('Key is not in the map')
                else:
                    return self.table[index].value1, self.table[index].value2, self.table[index].value3

        elif self.table[index] is None:
            raise KeyError('Key is not in the data base')
        else:
            raise KeyError('Hmm something has gone wrong here')

    def getitem_value(self, value1=None, value2=None, value3=None):
        self._binary_search(value1, value2, value3)
        in_file = open('service_files/output_result_search.txt', 'r')
        keys = in_file.read().splitlines()
        in_file.close()
        for key in keys:
            self.getitem(key)

    def _binary_search(self, value1=None, value2=None, value3=None):
        in_file = open('service_files/output_result_search.txt', 'w')
        out_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'r')
        hashes = out_file.read().splitlines()
        out_file.close()
        if (value1 is not None) and (value2 is None) and (value3 is None):
            for hash_ in hashes:
                if self.table[int(hash_)].value1 == value1:
                    print(self.table[int(hash_)].key, sep='\n', file=in_file)
        elif (value1 is None) and (value2 is not None) and (value3 is None):
            for hash_ in hashes:
                if self.table[int(hash_)].value2 == value2:
                    print(self.table[int(hash_)].key, sep='\n', file=in_file)
        elif (value1 is None) and (value2 is None) and (value3 is not None):
            for hash_ in hashes:
                if self.table[int(hash_)].value3 == value3:
                    print(self.table[int(hash_)].key, sep='\n', file=in_file)
        else:
            return 'Error! Please, chose ONE field of search!'
        in_file.close()

    def __get_hash_code(self, key):
        return hash(key) % len(self.table)

    def __resize_table(self):
        new_table = [None] * (len(self.table) * 2)
        for i in range(len(self.table)):
            new_table[i] = self.table[i]

        self.table = new_table

    def change(self, key, value1, value2=None, value3=None):
        entry = Entry(key, value1, value2, value3)
        entry.hash = self.__get_hash_code(key)
        if self.table[entry.hash] is not None:
            self.table[entry.hash] = entry

    def delitem(self, key):
        index = self.__get_hash_code(key)
        if self.table[index] is not None:
            if self.table[index].key == key:
                if self.table[index].is_deleted:
                    raise KeyError('Key is not in the map')
                else:
                    self.table[index].is_deleted = True

                    out_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'r')
                    hashes = out_file.read().splitlines()
                    out_file.close()

                    hashes.remove(str(self.table[index].hash))

                    in_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'w')
                    print(hashes, sep='\n', file=in_file)
                    in_file.close()

                    self.current_size -= 1

    def delitem_value(self, value1=None, value2=None, value3=None):
        self._binary_search(value1, value2, value3)
        in_file = open('service_files/output_result_search.txt', 'r')
        keys = in_file.read().splitlines()
        in_file.close()
        for key in keys:
            self.delitem(key)

    def open_data_base(self, name_file):
        if self.table:
            self.clean()
        with open(name_file) as out_file:
            data = out_file.read().splitlines()
        out_file.close()
        for item in data:
            item = item.split(';')
            self.add(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3])
        return None

    def save_data_base(self, name_file):
        in_file = open(name_file, 'w')
        out_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'r')
        hashes = out_file.read().splitlines()
        out_file.close()
        for hash_ in hashes:
            print(self.table[int(hash_)].key, self.table[int(hash_)].value1, self.table[int(hash_)].value2,
                  self.table[int(hash_)].value3, sep=';', file=in_file)
        in_file.close()
        return None

    def clean(self):
        file_hashes = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'w')
        file_hashes.close()
        file_output_result_search = open('service_files/output_result_search.txt', 'w')
        file_output_result_search.close()
        self.table = [None] * 10
        self.current_size = 0

    def __del__(self):
        os.remove('service_files/hashes.txt')
        os.remove('service_files/output_result_search.txt')
        del self.table
        del self.load_factor
        del self.current_size
```

Comment: Никто не знает в чем дело?... Или, возможно, чего-то не хватает в вопросе? Если сложно вникнуть в то, что написано выше, могу удалить все то, что не касается данной проблемы. Или же поподробнее описать сам код... Просто сама я никак не могу понять первопричину эдакой близорукости программы, смотрела разные сайты, видео, вроде как делаю по аналоги, но вот, ничего не происходит, программа все так же не видит вводимые данные...

Comment: сложно вникнуть, погуляйте минут 10 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я собрал в один модуль, так мне удобнее было смотреть и отметил то что поменял.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QMessageBox, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal

from mainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
from addRecordWindow import Ui_AddDialog


#from HashTable import *
class Entry:
    def __init__(self, key, value1, value2=None, value3=None):
        print("class Entry: ", key, value1, value2, value3)

        self.hash = None
        self.key = key
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
        self.value3 = value3
        self.is_deleted = False

    '''def __eq__(self, other):
        if (self.hash == other.hash and self.key == other.key and self.value1 == other.value1 and
                self.value2 == other.value2 and self.value3 == other.value3 and self.is_deleted == other.is_deleted):
            return True
        else:
            return False'''


class HashTable(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.table = [None] * 10
        self.load_factor = .75
        self.current_size = 0
        file_hashes = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'w')
        file_hashes.close()
        file_output_result_search = open('service_files/output_result_search.txt', 'w')
        file_output_result_search.close()

    def str(self):
        out_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'r')
        hashes = out_file.read().splitlines()
        out_file.close()
        for hash_ in hashes:
            print("def str(self): ", self.str_element(int(hash_)))
        return None

    def str_element(self, hash_):
        if self.table[hash_].value2 is None and self.table[hash_].value3 is None:
            item = ['{!r}: {!r}'.format(self.table[hash_].key, self.table[hash_].value1)]
        elif self.table[hash_].value2 is None:
            item = ['{!r}: [{!r}, {!r}]'.format(self.table[hash_].key, self.table[hash_].value1,
                                                self.table[hash_].value3)]
        elif self.table[hash_].value3 is None:
            item = ['{!r}: [{!r}, {!r}]'.format(self.table[hash_].key, self.table[hash_].value1,
                                                self.table[hash_].value2)]
        else:
            item = ['{!r}: [{!r}, {!r}, {!r}]'.format(self.table[hash_].key, self.table[hash_].value1,
                                                      self.table[hash_].value2, self.table[hash_].value3)]
        return '{' + ', '.join(item) + '}'

    '''def __setitem__(self, key, value1, value2=None, value3=None):
        self.__clear__()
        entry = Entry(key, value1, value2, value3)
        for i in range(len(self.table)):
            entry.hash = self.__get_hash_code(key)
            if self.table[entry.hash] is None or self.table[entry.hash].is_deleted:
                self.table[entry.hash] = entry
                in_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'w')
                print(entry.hash, sep='\n', file=in_file)
                in_file.close()
                self.current_size += 1
                if float(self.current_size) / len(self.table) >= self.load_factor:
                    self.__resize_table()'''

    def add(self, key, value1, value2=None, value3=None):
        print("def add (hashes.txt): ", key, value1, value2, value3)

        entry = Entry(key, value1, value2, value3)

        entry.hash = self.__get_hash_code(key)
        if self.table[entry.hash] is None or self.table[entry.hash].is_deleted:
            self.table[entry.hash] = entry
            in_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'a')

#            print("def add (hashes.txt): ", entry.hash)
#            print(entry.hash, sep='\n', file=in_file)

            in_file.close()
            self.current_size += 1
            if float(self.current_size) / len(self.table) >= self.load_factor:
                self.__resize_table()

    def getitem(self, key):
        index = self.__get_hash_code(key)
        if self.table[index] is not None:
            if self.table[index].key == key:
                if self.table[index].is_deleted:
                    raise KeyError('Key is not in the map')
                else:
                    return self.table[index].value1, self.table[index].value2, self.table[index].value3

        elif self.table[index] is None:
            raise KeyError('Key is not in the data base')
        else:
            raise KeyError('Hmm something has gone wrong here')

    def getitem_value(self, value1=None, value2=None, value3=None):
        self._binary_search(value1, value2, value3)
        in_file = open('service_files/output_result_search.txt', 'r')
        keys = in_file.read().splitlines()
        in_file.close()
        for key in keys:
            self.getitem(key)

    def _binary_search(self, value1=None, value2=None, value3=None):
        in_file  = open('service_files/output_result_search.txt', 'w')
        out_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'r')
        hashes   = out_file.read().splitlines()
        print("\ndef _binary_search: ", hashes)                  #@
        print("\ndef _binary_search: ", value1, value2, value3)  #@
        out_file.close()

        if (value1 is not None) and (value2 is None) and (value3 is None):
            for hash_ in hashes:
                if self.table[int(hash_)].value1 == value1:
                    print(self.table[int(hash_)].key, sep='\n', file=in_file)
        elif (value1 is None) and (value2 is not None) and (value3 is None):
            for hash_ in hashes:
                if self.table[int(hash_)].value2 == value2:
                    print(self.table[int(hash_)].key, sep='\n', file=in_file)
        elif (value1 is None) and (value2 is None) and (value3 is not None):
            for hash_ in hashes:
                if self.table[int(hash_)].value3 == value3:
                    print(self.table[int(hash_)].key, sep='\n', file=in_file)
        else:
            return 'Error! Please, chose ONE field of search!'

        print("def _binary_search: END ================== \n")    
        in_file.close()


    def __get_hash_code(self, key):
        print("def __get_hash_code: ", hash(key), len(self.table)) 
        return hash(key) % len(self.table)

    def __resize_table(self):
        new_table = [None] * (len(self.table) * 2)
        for i in range(len(self.table)):
            new_table[i] = self.table[i]
        self.table = new_table

    def change(self, key, value1, value2=None, value3=None):
        entry = Entry(key, value1, value2, value3)
        entry.hash = self.__get_hash_code(key)
        if self.table[entry.hash] is not None:
            self.table[entry.hash] = entry

    def delitem(self, key):
        index = self.__get_hash_code(key)
        if self.table[index] is not None:
            if self.table[index].key == key:
                if self.table[index].is_deleted:
                    raise KeyError('Key is not in the map')
                else:
                    self.table[index].is_deleted = True

                    out_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'r')
                    hashes = out_file.read().splitlines()
                    out_file.close()

                    hashes.remove(str(self.table[index].hash))

                    in_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'w')
                    print("delitem (hashes.txt, w): ", hashes)          #@
                    print(hashes, sep='\n', file=in_file)
                    in_file.close()

                    self.current_size -= 1

    def delitem_value(self, value1=None, value2=None, value3=None):
        self._binary_search(value1, value2, value3)
        in_file = open('service_files/output_result_search.txt', 'r')
        keys = in_file.read().splitlines()
        in_file.close()
        for key in keys:
            self.delitem(key)

    def open_data_base(self, name_file):
        if self.table:
            self.clean()
        with open(name_file) as out_file:
            data = out_file.read().splitlines()
        out_file.close()
        for item in data:
            item = item.split(';')
            self.add(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3])
        return None

    def save_data_base(self, name_file):
        in_file = open(name_file, 'w')
        out_file = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'r')
        hashes = out_file.read().splitlines()
        out_file.close()
        for hash_ in hashes:
            print("save_data_base: ", self.table[int(hash_)])   #@
            print(self.table[int(hash_)].key, self.table[int(hash_)].value1, self.table[int(hash_)].value2,
                  self.table[int(hash_)].value3, sep=';', file=in_file)
        in_file.close()
        return None      # ?

    def clean(self):
        file_hashes = open('service_files/hashes.txt', 'w')
        file_hashes.close()
        file_output_result_search = open('service_files/output_result_search.txt', 'w')
        file_output_result_search.close()
        self.table = [None] * 10
        self.current_size = 0

    def __del__(self):
        os.remove('service_files/hashes.txt')
        os.remove('service_files/output_result_search.txt')
        del self.table
        del self.load_factor
        del self.current_size


class AddRecordWin(QWidget, Ui_AddDialog):
    adding_data = pyqtSignal(str, str, str, str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    ''' ПЕРЕНЕС
        self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.send_data)                           
    def send_data(self):
        self.adding_data.emit(self.idEdit.text(), self.serialNameEdit.text(), 
                              self.numSeriesEdit.text(), self.isWatchedEdit.text())
        print("def send_data(self): ",
              self.idEdit.text(), 
              self.serialNameEdit.text(), 
              self.numSeriesEdit.text(), 
              self.isWatchedEdit.text()) # Пытаюсь посмотреть что лежит в собранных данных, временная мера
        self.close()
    '''

class MyWin(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.hash_table = None
        self.initialize_windows()
        self.work_with_menu()

    def handle_input(self, key, val1, val2, val3):
        if self.hash_table:
            self.hash_table.add(key, val1, val2, val3)
            self.hash_table.str() # Пытаюсь взглянуть на полученное, но все время выдает: {'': ['', '', '']}

    def initialize_windows(self):
        self.add_w = AddRecordWin()
# +++  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      
        self.add_w.adding_data.connect(self.handle_input)
        self.add_w.okButton.clicked.connect(self.send_data) 
# +++  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def work_with_menu(self):
        self.actionNew.triggered.connect(self.create_new_hash_table)
        self.actionOpen.triggered.connect(self.open_hash_table)
        self.actionSave.triggered.connect(self.save_hash_table)
        self.actionClean.triggered.connect(self.clean_hash_table)
        self.actionAddRecord.triggered.connect(self.show_AddRecordWin)

    def create_new_hash_table(self):
        self.hash_table = HashTable()

    def open_hash_table(self):
        self.create_new_hash_table()
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/data', "Image files (*.txt)")[0]
        self.hash_table.open_data_base(filename)
        self.hash_table.str()

    def save_hash_table(self):
        if self.hash_table.current_size:
            #self.hash_table.str()
            filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Open file', '/data', "Image files (*.txt)")[0]
            self.hash_table.save_data_base(filename)

    def clean_hash_table(self):
        self.hash_table.clean()

    def show_AddRecordWin(self):
        self.add_w.show()

# +++  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      
    def send_data(self):
        self.add_w.adding_data.emit(                                   # + self.add_w.
                                    self.add_w.idEdit.text(), 
                                    self.add_w.serialNameEdit.text(), 
                                    self.add_w.numSeriesEdit.text(), 
                                    self.add_w.isWatchedEdit.text())
        print("def send_data(self): ",
              self.add_w.idEdit.text(), 
              self.add_w.serialNameEdit.text(), 
              self.add_w.numSeriesEdit.text(), 
              self.add_w.isWatchedEdit.text()) # Пытаюсь посмотреть что лежит в собранных данных, временная мера
#        self.close()
        self.add_w.hide()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))
    print('Error: ', text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()
sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    my_app = MyWin()
    my_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

На самом деле вопрос в Двух строках. Как говорится, утро вечера мудренее :)

```
class AddRecordWin(QWidget, Ui_AddDialog):

    adding_data = pyqtSignal(str, str, str, str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.send_data)

    def send_data(self):
        self.adding_data.emit(self.idEdit.text(), self.serialNameEdit.text(), self.numSeriesEdit.text(),
                              self.isWatchedEdit.text())
        print(self.idEdit.text(), self.serialNameEdit.text(), self.numSeriesEdit.text(), self.isWatchedEdit.text()) # Пытаюсь посмотреть что лежит в собранных данных, временная мера
        self.close()


class MyWin(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.hash_table = None

        self.initialize_windows()
        self.work_with_menu()

    def handle_input(self, key, val1, val2, val3):
        if self.hash_table:
            self.hash_table.add(key, val1, val2, val3)
            self.hash_table.str() # Пытаюсь взглянуть на полученное, но все время выдает: {'': ['', '', '']}

    def initialize_windows(self):
        self.add_w = AddRecordWin()

        self.add_w.adding_data[str, str, str, str].connect(self.handle_input)     # <<< +++++ <<<

    def work_with_menu(self):
        self.actionNew.triggered.connect(self.create_new_hash_table)
        self.actionOpen.triggered.connect(self.open_hash_table)
        self.actionSave.triggered.connect(self.save_hash_table)
        self.actionClean.triggered.connect(self.clean_hash_table)
        self.actionAddRecord.triggered.connect(self.show_AddRecordWin)

    def create_new_hash_table(self):
        self.hash_table = HashTable()

    def open_hash_table(self):
        self.create_new_hash_table()
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/data', "Image files (*.txt)")[0]
        self.hash_table.open_data_base(filename)
        self.hash_table.str()

    def save_hash_table(self):
        if self.hash_table.current_size:
            #self.hash_table.str()
            filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Open file', '/data', "Image files (*.txt)")[0]
            self.hash_table.save_data_base(filename)

    def clean_hash_table(self):
        self.hash_table.clean()

    def show_AddRecordWin(self):

#        self.add_w.setupUi(self)                                   # <<<< удалить <<<<<<<<< ----

        self.add_w.show()
#        self.add_w.adding_data[str, str, str, str].connect(self.handle_input) # <<<< перенес <<<<<<<<< ----
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам еще раз огромное! Правда я еще не смогла это "внедрить" в то, что у меня написано (сама уже путаюсь, т.к. сижу не менее 8 часов... или больше:)) ) Но я рядышком создала файл, туда все перекопировала, запустила, еще раз обрадовалась, что работает сие чудо :) И также благодарю Вас за комментарии в ранее заданных вопросах, они очень полезны для меня как новичка на этом сайте!

Comment: @treiina  я видимо ночью перестарался :). Посмотрите второй ответ и вам станет понятно.